# React table- doesn't refresh content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am trying to refresh content in the table generated with this library [react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table). However, for some reason, it doesn't work, even though I change the state of the parameter which I pass to the Component.

```
<ReactTable
   data={this.state.data}
   columns={this.state.headers}
/>
```

And the function which changes data:

```
  let data= this.state.data;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i].name="TEST"
  }
  this.setState({data: data})
```

I can see that the data has changed but the content of the table stays the same.

Comment: As a suggestion, do not assign your state data into a variable like that. Use `Object.assign` or spread syntax: `let data = [ ...this.state.data ]` Also, do not change a key's value like that, since if you change with this way, your original object mutates, too. Use `.map` as suggested @Shishir Arora's answer. This applies to spread syntax since it makes a shallow copy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
let data= this.state.data;
const newData = data.map(d=>({...d, name:"Test"}));
this.setState({data: newData})
```

Use above code. Reason: React does not see mutation.